# Function in PHP file doesn't work, when file is called using curl

Tags: php, wordpress, curl

I've got on my server PHP file, which download something using curl from another server, and save it to db in nested php function. This process is little time-consuming, when I open it in my browser, I must wait ca. 1 minute, but all downloaded records are correct.

Problem is in CRON wget/curl download. When I use 
wget http://myserver/myscript.php, or curl http://myserver/myscript.php, connection is closed after 1 byte, and nothing happens on server...

Where make I mistake? Maybe some headers? Why wget/curl don't wait on end of my PHP function like browser? I hope, that require of wp-load.php (I must use for it some Wordpress functions) isn't problem?

Many thanks for responses

Comment: Could you add the code?

Answer (score 0):

Code:

```
<?php
define('WP_USE_THEMES', false);
require_once("wp-load.php");

$licznik = 0;
// WP_Query arguments
$args = array (
    'post_type'              => array( 'easy-rooms' ),
    'posts_per_page'        => 30
);

// The Query
$query = new WP_Query( $args );

// The Loop
if ( $query->have_posts() ) {
    while ( $query->have_posts() ) {        

        $query->the_post();

         $fields = array( 
                "funkcja" => "lista_rezerwacji",
                "id_pokoju" => get_the_ID()
        );      

          $postvars = '';

          foreach($fields as $key=>$value) {
            $postvars .= $key . "=" . $value . "&";
          }
          rtrim($fields_string, '&');

          $url = "http://some.remote.script.to.download.sth.by.curl";

          $ch = curl_init();
          curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
          curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, 1);                //0 for a get request
          curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postvars);
          curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
          curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT ,3);
          curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 120);
          $response = curl_exec($ch);
          curl_close ($ch);

          echo $response;


 //THIS IS FUNCTION IN SOME WORDPRESS PLUGIN, WHICH DOESN'T WORK WHEN I WGET/CURL THIS SCRIPT
          set_reservations($response, get_the_ID());

          $licznik++;


    }
} else {
    // no posts found
}

// Restore original Post Data
print_r($licznik);
wp_reset_postdata();

?>
```